# Extract jpeg File

Tags: archive, compression, archive-utility

Often files are hidden in `.jpg` files simply by opening them up with 7zip, then closing them again. Mac OS X archive utility does not have this ability. Is there any software available for osx that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all you need to do is change the file extension from .JPG or .JPEG to .zip. If it is indeed a zip file the O/S' unzip program should unzip it.

Failing that I use The Unarchiver

http://unarchiver.c3.cx

As a replacement for O/S X's built-in zip compression utility as it handles more formats.